# PCL zoom out functionality

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am new to Point Cloud Library (PCL) and C++ programming. I load multiple `.ply` files given as the arguments (say `test0.ply`,`test1.ply`...`test99.ply`) and visualize them one after another as if they are frames of videos.

Below is what I've tried so far. How can I get farther from the model during each frame (zoom out) ? The `setCameraPosition` function looks related, but the description is confusing.

UPDATE: We need to find the camera's `current_position` and play with it. Just like zoom in/out.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/common/transforms.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

// This function displays the help
void showHelp(char *program_name)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Usage: " << program_name << " cloud_filename.[pcd|ply]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-h: Show this help." << std::endl;
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Show help
    if (pcl::console::find_switch(argc, argv, "-h") || pcl::console::find_switch(argc, argv, "--help"))
    {
        showHelp(argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    // Fetch point cloud filename in arguments | Works with PLY files
    std::vector<int> filenames;

    filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument(argc, argv, ".ply");

    // Visualization 
    printf("\n Point cloud colors :\n"
        " \t white \t = \t original point cloud \n");

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer(" Point Cloud Visualizer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0); // Set background to a dark grey

                                                    // Load file | Works with PLY files
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr source_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());

    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
//      int v1(0);
//      viewer.createViewPort(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, v1);
        i++;
        cout << argv[filenames[i % 10]] << endl;

        if (pcl::io::loadPLYFile(argv[filenames[i % 10]], *source_cloud) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error loading point cloud " << argv[filenames[(i % 10) + 1]] << std::endl << std::endl;
            showHelp(argv[(i % 10) + 1]);
            return -1;
        }


        // Define R,G,B colors for the point cloud 
        pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(source_cloud);

        // We add the point cloud to the viewer and pass the color handler 

        viewer.addPointCloud(source_cloud, rgb, "original_cloud" + i);
        viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "original_cloud" + i);

        viewer.spinOnce();
        viewer.removePointCloud("original_cloud" + i);
    }

    return 0;
} // End main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track and setCameraPosition() should be what you are looking for. Here is some example code that focus the camera on a specific point and places the camera 5 meters away in the y dimension.

```
    pcl::PointXYZI center = centerPoint(cloud);
    viewer->setCameraPosition(center.x, center.y - 5, center.z, 0, 0, 1);

    std::vector<pcl::visualization::Camera> cams;
    viewer->getCameras(cams);

    for (auto&& camera : cams)
    {
        camera.focal[0] = center.x;
        camera.focal[1] = center.y;
        camera.focal[2] = center.z;
    }

    viewer->setCameraParameters(cams[0]);
```

Comment: So just calling the `setCameraPosition(center.x, center.y - 5, center.z, 0, 0, 1);` doesn't work itself? What is the `camera.focal` ones do exactly?

Comment: btw, `identifier "centerPoint" is undefined`

Comment: I believe camera.focal sets up where the camera should focus at. This is separate from where the camera should be positioned at in space. You could probably do the same sort of thing with the other overloaded call to setCameraPosition()

Comment: Yes it works. But it places it in a weird location. I have to play around with it. So what are the metrics here? Also is there any ways for relative distance? (e.g. current view, just go -5 in Z axis)

Comment: We need to find the camera's `current_position` and play with it. Just like zoom in/out.